# Ask user for starting and stopping point within the array?

Tags: c#, arrays

In C# how do i ask user for starting and stopping point within the array?

Below is my code so far:

---

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] num = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
        double n = num.Length;

        Console.Write("Elements of, arrary are:" + Environment.NewLine);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num[i]);
        }
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + num[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of elements:" + sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of ways.  You can read input from the console, read in a file, create a form, make a request to a website or other resource over a network, you could use command line arguments, I could go on.

Comment: It's super unclear what 'ask user for starting and stopping point within the array' means

Comment: Write something that says: "HEY USER! WHERE YOU WANNA STOP?" Then they insert a number and you stop there.

Comment: that was the question in the book...Create and fill a one dimensional array of doubles. Then ask the user for a starting and stopping position within the array. Display the sum all of the numbers in the array between the start and stop positions.

Comment: Do you want user to decide 0 and n?

Comment: if @Nurgle was running for something I'd vote for him based on that answer

Answer (score 1):

You'll take the sum of the elements between starting and stopping point, as I guess. Take two inputs from the user and assign them to starting and ending points to the `for-loop`. Such as:

```
 int startingPoint = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 int endingPoint = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 for(int i = startingPoint; i <= endingPoint; i++)
 {
      //take sum etc.
 }
```

Don't forget to inform the user about the element values in the array and what input value they are entering at that moment.

Another important thing here is to control the inputs. They should be numeric and between `0-n`, starting point should be smaller than ending point.

For numeric control you can write like follows:

```
if (int.TryParse(n, out startingPoint))
{
     // operate here
} 
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("That's why I don't trust you, enter a numeric value please.");
}
```

`startingPoint` should be between `0-n` and cannot be `n`. To control it:

```
if (startingPoint >= 0 && startingPoint < n)
{
     // operate here
} 
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 0 and " + n + ".");
}
```

After taking `startingPoint` successfully, you should control if `endingPoint`. It should be between `startingPoint-n`. After controlling for being numeric you can write as follows:

```
if (endingPoint >= startingPoint && endingPoint < n)
{
     // operate here
} 
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between " + startingPoint + " and " + n + ".");
}
```

I don't know what can I explain more for this question. Please let me know for further problems.

Comment: don't worry about testing the user input though.  I can tell you that users ALWAYS provide good input, and any validation is merely a waste of memory space.

Comment: wow, calm down. i was just doing an edit on user input controls before i saw your comment.

Comment: I'm sorry that was supposed to be more funny, not condescending.  I should've used more emoticons.

Comment: my lack of humor. sorry :)

Comment: I want to upvote that first comment because its hilarious. but I know someday someone will read it and believe it.

Comment: @Jonesy how about now :) if i do exhaustive answering to this types of questions, it seems like i'm being sarcastic, that's why i made it short at first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prompt the user for the start and end indexes:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter start index");
string startIndexAsString = Console.ReadLine();
int startIndex = int.Parse(startIndexAsString);

Console.WriteLine("Please enter end index");
string endIndexAsString = Console.ReadLine();
int endIndex = int.Parse(endIndexAsString);

var sum = num.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex - startIndex + 1).Sum();
```

Comment: solid and professional answer, but i think we might give easy answers with simpler elements as in the question's code. please don't get me wrong, just an opinion.

Comment: I figured out how to start and stop Ismet Alkan, but error handling isn't working....